# flashbuilder 4.5 can't find import flash.display.*;

Tags: flash-builder

i opened a flash pro project in flashbuilder 4.5 but it puts a question mark next to my import statements for example:
import flash.display.*;
I have tried rebuilding the project in a new folder. I have the latest SDK. why would Flashbuilder have a problem finding flash.display.*; or import flash.events.*; very irritating is there a way to fix this or should i just continue to use textmate to code as3?

Comment: Does it compile and run through flashbuilder

Answer (score 12):

I'm having this issue myself from time to time, even in current Flash Builder 4.5 (never figured out how to replicate it though).

**To solve it do this:**
Right click on your project in Project Explorer tab of Flash Builder > Properties
Once there select ActioScript Build Path > Library path > Add SWC folder
Select this directory C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP9

(optionaly) If you wish to target FP10, add this dir instead C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP10

Comment: Still Relevant... Was ripping out my fingernails trying to figure this out. Thanks Much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import flash.display.*;
```

You were missing the .*

Comment: thanks for your response. actually that was a typo in my post but not in my code. I did have the wildcard in my import statement and the question marks are still there. The code hinting features in flex builder are nice but it's not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found:

When I create a new Flash Professional project from FlashBuilder 4.5, the Flash IDE opens and my flash.display.Sprite import looks like it's broken.

If I close the Flash IDE, FlashBuilder opens it right back up again, and my imports look fine after that.

YMMV